# Odd results when adding artificial delays to C++ code. Embedded Linux

Tags: c++, linux, performance, embedded

I have been looking at the performance of our C++ server application running on embedded Linux (ARM).  The pseudo code for the main processing loop of the server is this -

```
for i = 1 to 1000
  Process item i
  Sleep for 20 ms
```

The processing for one item takes about 2ms.  The "Sleep" here is really a call to the Poco library to do a "tryWait" on an event.  If the event is fired (which it never is in my tests) or the time expires, it comes returns.  I don't know what system call this equates to.  Although we ask for a 2ms block, it turns out to be roughly 20ms. I can live with that - that's not the problem. The sleep is just an artificial delay so that other threads in the process are not starved.

The loop takes about 24 seconds to go through 1000 items.

The problem is, we changed the way the sleep is used so that we had a bit more control.  I mean - 20ms delay for 2ms processing doesn't allow us to do much processing.  With this new parameter set to a certain value it does something like this -

```
For i = 1 to 1000
  Process item i
  if i % 50 == 0 then sleep for 1000ms
```

That's the rough code, in reality the number of sleeps is slightly different and it happens to work out at a 24s cycle to get through all the items - just as before.

So we are doing exactly the same amount of processing in the same amount of time.

**Problem 1** - the CPU usage for the original code is reported at around 1% (it varies a little but that's about average) and the CPU usage reported for the new code is about 5%.  I think they should be the same.

Well perhaps this CPU reporting isn't accurate so I thought I'd sort a large text file at the same time and see how much it's slowed up by our server.  This is a CPU bound process (98% CPU usage according to top).  The results are very odd.  With the old code, the time taken to sort the file goes up by 21% when our server is running.

**Problem 2** - If the server is only using 1% of the CPU then wouldn't the time taken to do the sort be pretty much the same?

Also, the time taken to go through all the items doesn't change - it's still 24 seconds with or without the sort running.

Then I tried the new code, it only slows the sort down by about 12% but it now takes about 40% longer to get through all the items it has to process.

**Problem 3** - Why do the two ways of introducing an artificial delay cause such different results.  It seems that the server which sleeps more frequently but for a minimum time is getting more priority.

I have a half baked theory on the last one - whatever the system call that is used to do the "sleep" is switching back to the server process when the time is elapsed.  This gives the process another bite at the time slice on a regular basis.

Any help appreciated.  I suspect I'm just not understanding it correctly and that things are more complicated than I thought.  I can provide more details if required.

Thanks.

**Update:** replaced tryWait(2) with usleep(2000) - no change.  In fact, sched_yield() does the same.

Comment: 'The "Sleep" here is really a call to the Poco library to do a "tryWait" on an event.' - it sounds like you are comparing apples to oranges. What happens if you replace the Poco library call with an ordinary sleep like in the other example? From reading your question you seem to want ideas so I am trying to be helpful. ;)

Comment: I think you would find it informative to read about **scheduler** strategies and their various behavior.

Comment: I could try replacing tryWait but it's still apples with apples as both bits of code use the same system.  I might try it anyway!

Not sure if reading about general scheduling will help explain why the CPU is reported as 1% when the loop does 2s of processing and 20s of "sleeping".  That should be about 10%. Thanks for replies.

Comment: `if i % 50 == 0` Seeing as this is tagged in embedded, are you actually using modulo division?  Without hardware support, software modulo is slow, sucky, and inconsistent.  This might explain the 1% to 5% CPU usage discrepancy.  Use an incremented variable instead of modulo every cycle (unless it's optimized out, then it doesn't matter obviously).

Comment: Hello - I don't really use modulo.  It's more complicated than that but it's still not significant as the processing per item is huge - 1000's of lines of code.  Things are put on a list, another thread takes it off etc.  It's a comms stack.  Since my posting I have replaced tryWait with usleep and also replaced the processing with a tight loop just checking a timer until 2ms is up (to cut out the comms stack).  Neither made any difference. I do 2ms processing, 20ms sleep, that should be 10% CPU but the CPU usage reported by the OS is 1%.  QED.

Comment: @aggieboy : I think we can assume any hardware running Linux will have a hardware divide integer divide operation. I doubt that has any significance compared with the 2ms processing time.

Answer (score 0):

Well I can at least answer problem 1 and problem 2 (as they are the same issue).

After trying out various options in the actual server code, we came to the conclusion that the CPU reporting from the OS is incorrect.  It's quite result so to make sure, I wrote a stand alone program that doesn't use Poco or any of our code.  Just plain Linux system calls and standard C++ features.  It implements the pseudo code above.  The processing is replaced with a tight loop just checking the elapsed time to see if 2ms is up.  The sleeps are proper sleeps.

The small test program shows exactly the same problem.  i.e. doing the same amount of processing but splitting up the way the sleep function is called, produces very different results for CPU usage.  In the case of the test program, the reported CPU usage was 0.0078 seconds using 1000 20ms sleeps but 1.96875 when a less frequent 1000ms sleep was used.  The amount of processing done is the same.

Running the test on a Linux PC did not show the problem.  Both ways of sleeping produced exactly the same CPU usage.

So clearly a problem with our embedded system and the way it measures CPU time when a process is yielding so often (you get the same problem with sched_yeild instead of a sleep).

Update:  Here's the code.  RunLoop is where the main bit is done  -

```
int sleepCount;

double getCPUTime( )
{
  clockid_t id = CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID;
  struct timespec ts;
  if ( id != (clockid_t)-1 && clock_gettime( id, &ts ) != -1 )
    return (double)ts.tv_sec +
           (double)ts.tv_nsec / 1000000000.0;
  return -1;
}

double GetElapsedMilliseconds(const timeval& startTime)
{
  timeval endTime;
  gettimeofday(&endTime, NULL);
  double elapsedTime = (endTime.tv_sec - startTime.tv_sec) * 1000.0;      // sec to ms
  elapsedTime += (endTime.tv_usec - startTime.tv_usec) / 1000.0;   // us to ms
  return elapsedTime;
}

void SleepMilliseconds(int milliseconds)
{
  timeval startTime;
  gettimeofday(&startTime, NULL);
  usleep(milliseconds * 1000);
  double elapsedMilliseconds = GetElapsedMilliseconds(startTime);
  if (elapsedMilliseconds > milliseconds + 0.3)
    std::cout << "Sleep took longer than it should " << elapsedMilliseconds;

  sleepCount++;
}

void DoSomeProcessingForAnItem()
{
  timeval startTime;
  gettimeofday(&startTime, NULL);
  double processingTimeMilliseconds = 2.0;
  double elapsedMilliseconds;
  do
  {
    elapsedMilliseconds = GetElapsedMilliseconds(startTime);
  } while (elapsedMilliseconds <= processingTimeMilliseconds);
  if (elapsedMilliseconds > processingTimeMilliseconds + 0.1)
    std::cout << "Processing took longer than it should " << elapsedMilliseconds;
}

void RunLoop(bool longSleep)
{
  int numberOfItems = 1000;
  timeval startTime;
  gettimeofday(&startTime, NULL);
  timeval startMainLoopTime;
  gettimeofday(&startMainLoopTime, NULL);
  for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++)
  {
    DoSomeProcessingForAnItem();
    double elapsedMilliseconds = GetElapsedMilliseconds(startTime);
    if (elapsedMilliseconds > 100)
    {
      std::cout << "Item count = " << i << "\n";
      if (longSleep)
      {
        SleepMilliseconds(1000);
      }
      gettimeofday(&startTime, NULL);
    }
    if (longSleep == false)
    {
      // Does 1000 * 20 ms sleeps.
      SleepMilliseconds(20);
    }
  }
  double elapsedMilliseconds = GetElapsedMilliseconds(startMainLoopTime);
  std::cout << "Main loop took " << elapsedMilliseconds / 1000 <<" seconds\n";
}

void DoTest(bool longSleep)
{
  timeval startTime;
  gettimeofday(&startTime, NULL);
  double startCPUtime = getCPUTime();
  sleepCount = 0;

  int runLoopCount = 1;
  for (int i = 0; i < runLoopCount; i++)
  {
    RunLoop(longSleep);
    std::cout << "**** Done one loop of processing ****\n";
  }

  double endCPUtime = getCPUTime();

  std::cout << "Elapsed time is " <<GetElapsedMilliseconds(startTime) / 1000 << " seconds\n";
  std::cout << "CPU time used is " <<  endCPUtime - startCPUtime << " seconds\n";
  std::cout << "Sleep count " <<  sleepCount << "\n";
}

void testLong()
{
  std::cout << "Running testLong\n";
  DoTest(true);
}

void testShort()
{
  std::cout << "Running testShort\n";
  DoTest(false);
}
```

Comment: Different does not mean "wrong".  You are expecting equivalence between two schemes with vastly different overhead, and just because you *appear* to see it (on what is likely a multi-core desktop machine) does not mean that is actually what happens.  I'd say the measurements that seem to show equivalence are as, if not, more suspect than those which show a difference.

Comment: I'll add my code and see if you still think the same!  :-)  I have a tight loop that will not end until a certain time has elapsed.  It waits for 2ms and it does that 1000 times.  How can that ever use 0.0078 ms in total?